# Separate Chaining vs random probing

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

I'm currently considering options for the collision resolution strategy for a hashtable. When I originally was taught about the implementation of hashtables, I learned that Separate Chaining was the preferred choice compared to linear probing which had a lot of pitfalls. After researching online, I discovered that the underlying implementation of the python dictionary uses a technique called random probing to resolve collisions as explained in the docstring from [this CPython file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b871ace5c58f/Objects/dictobject.c#l106).

Given that it is used in the official dictionary implementation, it seems like it would probably be the most efficient way to resolve hashtable collisions. But given the complexity of implementing random probing and since separate chaining is generally an accepted collision strategy, is there any reason that I shouldn't use separate chaining in favor of random probing?

Comment: Why worry about implementation? You can just use a dictionary.

Comment: The random probing really isn't that complicated, it's a couple arithmetic operations: `j = ((5*j) + 1) mod 2**i`

Comment: @user3080953 I just don't understand the intuition behind why it should even be used as a preferred choice over separate chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons I can think of:

1) Probing is cheaper than separate chaining (it doesn't require memory allocation to expand a linked list or whatever data structure is used to store the elements)

2) Probing is (slightly) more space efficient than chaining, since you don't need to store the overhead from the data structure, (e.g. next pointers for linked lists)